# Test cell value if is in the interval with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I want to use `arrayformula` on the top of my row to spam its calculations in the column. In my sheet I have to test if the value on the cell of column `F` (Teste) is on the interval (for instance if cell `F18 = 2 < 3` is `TRUE`). Here's the code on the cell `G1` I've written:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(G:G)=1;"Classe";IF(AND(F2:F>0;F2:F<3);"ok";1)))
```

But instead of computing the `AND(F2:F>0;F2:F<3)` it just returns `FALSE`. So the question is: how do I write such formula that takes a value on a cell and compares if it is on the interval I want and then show "ok"? Thank you for the help!

Image of my sheet:

[My spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJV1W.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(G:G)=1; "Classe"; IF((F2:F>0)*(F2:F<3); "ok"; 1)))
```